# Python - getting information from nodes

Tags: python

I've been trying to get information from a site, and recently found out that is stored in childNodes[0].data.
I'm pretty new to python and never tried scripting against websites.

Somebody told me I could make a tmp.xml file, and extract the information from there, but as it's only getting the source code(which I think is of no use for me), I don't get any results.

Current code:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(get_link)
html = response.read()
with open("tmp.xml", "w") as f:
    f.write(html)
dom = parse("tmp.xml")
name = dom.getElementsByTagName("name[0].firstChild.nodeValue")
```

I've also tried using 'dom = parse(html)' without better result.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName()` takes an element name, not an expression. It is highly unlikely that there are tags in the page you are loading that contain `<name[0].firstChild.nodeValue>` tags.

If you are loading HTML, use a HTML parser instead, like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). For XML, using the [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is a lot easier than using the (archaic and very verbose) DOM API.

Neither approach requires that you first save the source to disk, both APIs can parse directly from the response object returned by `urllib2`.

```
# HTML
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = urllib2.urlopen(get_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), from_encoding=response.headers.getparam('charset'))

print soup.find('title').text
```

or

```
# XML
import urllib2
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

response = urllib2.urlopen(get_link)
tree = ET.parse(response)

print tree.find('elementname').text
```